# jQuery FullCalendar: How to load events on Next and Previous button click

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a page where I show events of next 30 days. 
How do I refresh the calendar when the user clicks the Next on month view OR when user keeps clicking the Next button in Week/Day view when it goes beyond 30 days?

If I click the next button for 5th time in week view, I am not seeing any events on calendar since I have only events for 4 week.

I want to pull the data from server via ajax and refresh the calendar.

Here is my current code:

On Page load I call like this:

```
GetFutureMeetingsForTimeSpan(1, 30);

function GetFutureMeetingsForTimeSpan(startDaysFromNow, endDaysFromNow) {            
            var obMtgs;
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xmlHttp.status == '200') {
                        try {                            
                            var arrMtgs = new Array();
                            var meetingObjectArray = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                            var startTime = '', endTime = '';
                            var yr1 = 0, mo1 = 0, day1 = 0, hr1 = 0, min1 = 0;
                            var yr2 = 0, mo2 = 0, day2 = 0, hr2 = 0, min2 = 0;
                            for (var i = 0; i < meetingObjectArray.length; i++) {                                
                                obMtgs = new Object();
                                obMtgs.id = meetingObjectArray[i].ID;        
                                obMtgs.title = meetingObjectArray[i].ExchangeResource.Subject;


                                obMtgs.start = new Date(yr1, mo1, day1, hr1, min1, 0);                                
                                obMtgs.end = new Date(yr2, mo2, day2, hr2, min2, 0);

                                arrMtgs.push(obMtgs);
                            }

                            //populate the calendar with events array                            
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                                theme: true,
                                header: {
                                    left: 'prev,next today',
                                    center: 'title',
                                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                                },
                                disableDragging: true,
                                disableResizing: true,
                                editable: true,
                                events: arrMtgs,                                
                                eventRender: function (event,element){ 
                                    //code removed
                                },
                                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                                    //code removed
                                },
                                viewDisplay: function (view) {
                                    //code removed
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        catch (e) {
                            alert('decode failed! msg=' + e.message);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Failed to get meetings! status=' + xmlHttp.status);
                    }
                }
            }

            //load events from server via webservice using ajax
            var url = server_part + "/Meeting/Schedule/Future/TimeSpan/";
            url += "?startDaysFromNow=" + startDaysFromNow;
            url += "&endDaysFromNow=" + endDaysFromNow;
            url += "&APIKey=asjdasjdhhksajhd";

            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xmlHttp.send();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Happens because you are initializing the cal with preset `events:arrMtgs`.
Instead, let FC request the events it needs, like in the example doc: [events fun](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/) or [json feed](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/).
Also, you can do simpler ajax requests with jQuery `$.ajax`.

Comment: Now I am using events: function (start, end, callback) {}

Comment: Yes, that's what you needed to do. The second answer below just expands on the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle here. Instead of having your `GetFutureMeetingsForTimeSpan` function reinitialize your FC instance every time it is called, you should initialize your FC *only once*, and let FC call the `GetFutureMeetingsForTimeSpan` function (or some variant of it).

So I'd suggest you create your FC instance when it becomes visible the first time, and use the events function to load events when necessary:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            theme: true,
            header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            disableDragging: true,
            disableResizing: true,
            editable: true,
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
                    // populate arrMtgs as you're used to
                    // using the start and end parameters,
                    // or see MaxD's answer for alternatives
                    callback(arrMtgs);
            },
            eventRender: function (event,element){ 
                    //code removed
            },
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    //code removed
            },
            viewDisplay: function (view) {
                    //code removed
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as u, where the calendar has a very bad performance. until i realized the following:
the ajax URL that fullcalendar return events from, by default associate start and end params with ajax request. these start and end represent the first date and last date of events shown on each single calendar page (which can be changed by the arrow of "next" and "previous"). so in your events code that returns all events, u can limit them by this startand end. 
the code on your controller can be:

```
    Event.where(:start_at => DateTime.strptime(params[:start],'%s')..DateTime.strptime(params[:end],'%s'))
```