# How can i call ajax request when i click on next ,prev ,month button of FullCalender?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-1

i am using **FullCalender**  1.9 version. that is too old. but i am bound with this.

now issue is , i am putting full data that more than 2000. so my calendar taking long time to load. so i decided that when we click on Today ,Next ,PREV , Month button then it call a ajax request and data will load from backend server.

i used many solution but no any solution working for me. i took reference of this [jquery fullcalendar how to load events on next and previous button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269451/jquery-fullcalendar-how-to-load-events-on-next-and-previous-button-click)  but could not understand.

please help me.

my JS code is

```
 $(function () { // document ready

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        viewRender: function(view, element) { },
        
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'yellow');
            url = '{{ route("boking-details", 'XXX') }}'.replace('XXX', calEvent.id);
            $.fancybox.destroy();
            element = '<a id="openFancybox"  data-type="ajax" data-src="' + url + '" href="javascript:;"></a>'
            $(".element").html(element);
            $("#openFancybox").fancybox();
            $("#openFancybox").click();
        },

        /*eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {

            if (confirm("Are you sure about this change?"+ " was dropped on " + event.start.format())) {
                changeBooking(event, delta, revertFunc);
            }
        },*/

        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
            if (confirm("This booking has now been moved."+ " with booking time " + event.start.format() )) {
                changeBooking(event, delta, revertFunc);

                //savedrop(event.id,event.start,event.end);    
            } else {
                $('.popover').popover('hide');
                revertFunc();
            }
        },

        eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
          $el.popover({
            title: eventObj.title,
            content: eventObj.description,
            trigger: 'hover',
            placement: 'top',
            container: 'body'
          });
        },

        /*//latest
        eventMouseover: function( event, jsEvent, view ) { 
            var item = $(this);
            if(item.find('.nube').length == 0){
                var info = '<span class="nube"><h2>'+event.title+'</h2> <p class="text">'+event.description+'</p></span>';
                item.append(info);
            }
            if(parseInt(item.css('top')) <= 200){
                item.find('.nube').css({'top': 20,'bottom':'auto'});
                item.parent().find('.fc-event').addClass('z0');
            }
            item.find('.nube').stop(true,true).fadeIn();
        },
        eventMouseout: function( event, jsEvent, view ) { 
            var item = $(this);
            item.find('.nube').stop(true,true).fadeOut();
        },*/

        /*eventMouseover: function (calEvent, jsEvent) {
            var xOffset = 0;
            var yOffset = 0;
            var tiptext;
            //var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');                
            //tiptext = "<strong>" + calEvent.title + "</strong>" + "<br>" + tiptext;
            $("body").append("<p class='btn btn-secondary' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' id='tooltip'> <strong>" + calEvent.title + "</strong>" + "<br>" + calEvent.description + "</p>");
            $("#tooltip")
                .css("z-index", 91000)
                .css("position", "absolute")
                .css("top", ($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() + yOffset) + "px")
                .css("left", ($(this).offset().left + xOffset) + "px")
                .fadeIn(400);                    
        },
        eventMouseout: function (calEvent, jsEvent) {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
        },*/

        timeFormat : "H(:mm)",
        //slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
        displayEventTime: false,
        //  now: '2018-11-07',
        editable: true, // enable draggable events
        dragRevertDuration: 1000,
        aspectRatio: 2.5,
        scrollTime: '10:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime

        //slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
        //minTime: '06:30:00',
        //maxTime: '19:30:00',
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        slotLabelInterval: 15,
        //lazyFetching: true,
        header: {
            left: 'today, prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineMonth,timelineWeek,timelineDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
        views: {
            timelineThreeDays: {
                type: 'timeline',
                duration: {days: 3}
            },
            timelineWeek: {
                type: 'timeline',
                dayOfMonthFormat: 'ddd DD/MM',
                //titleFormat: '(d MMMM yyyy)'
                //titleFormat:"HH",
            },
            timelineDay: {
                type: 'timeline',
                //timeFormat: 'H:mm',
                slotLabelFormat:"HH",
            }
        },
        resourceLabelText: 'Drivers',
        resources: <?= json_encode($resources) ?>,
        events: <?= json_encode($events) ?>
    });
});
```

Comment: You can set up `events` to be a json feed. When view is changed the plugin makes the request for you and sends dates as params

Comment: Don't handle these buttons directly. Use an event feed and then fullCalendar will automatically fetch more events from your server when it needs them. Details here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/events-json-feed